# Blender 4.0 API: Cannot access Node Tree Inputs value within layout.prop

Tags: python, user-interface, blender

The new API changes to the Blender Node Tree structure doesn't seem to provide any way to programmatically get/set actual values of sockets in layout.prop.
Previously, a user would use `.inputs` or `.outputs`, however the closest I can get to accessing it is the default value, which doesn't actually change anything, using
`obj.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["socket_id"]`
I've tried about 500 different approaches to get a decent result, but just can't seem to figure one out.

The goal is for a slider to be generated in a panel, which allows the user to adjust the group input's values. While this can be done using the modifier window, it doesn't seem possible to do it outside of that environment.

Run the script
Open the Modifiers property window
Open the Sidebar > Object Generator
Compare the changes when adjusting the slider

```
import bpy
import random
from bpy.types import Panel


def purge_orphans():
    """
    Remove all orphan data blocks

    see this from more info:
    https://youtu.be/3rNqVPtbhzc?t=149
    """
    if bpy.app.version >= (3, 0, 0):
        # run this only for Blender versions 3.0 and higher
        bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge(do_local_ids=True, do_linked_ids=True, do_recursive=True)
    else:
        # run this only for Blender versions lower than 3.0
        # call purge_orphans() recursively until there are no more orphan data blocks to purge
        result = bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge()
        if result.pop() != "CANCELLED":
            purge_orphans()


def clean_scene():
    """
    Removing all of the objects, collection, materials, particles,
    textures, images, curves, meshes, actions, nodes, and worlds from the scene

    Checkout this video explanation with example

    "How to clean the scene with Python in Blender (with examples)"
    https://youtu.be/3rNqVPtbhzc
    """
    # make sure the active object is not in Edit Mode
    if bpy.context.active_object and bpy.context.active_object.mode == "EDIT":
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

    # make sure non of the objects are hidden from the viewport, selection, or disabled
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        obj.hide_set(False)
        obj.hide_select = False
        obj.hide_viewport = False

    # select all the object and delete them (just like pressing A + X + D in the viewport)
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="SELECT")
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    # find all the collections and remove them
    collection_names = [col.name for col in bpy.data.collections]
    for name in collection_names:
        bpy.data.collections.remove(bpy.data.collections[name])

    # in the case when you modify the world shader
    # delete and recreate the world object
    world_names = [world.name for world in bpy.data.worlds]
    for name in world_names:
        bpy.data.worlds.remove(bpy.data.worlds[name])
    # create a new world data block
    bpy.ops.world.new()
    bpy.context.scene.world = bpy.data.worlds["World"]

    purge_orphans()


def link_nodes(node_tree, from_node, to_node, from_socket_num=0, to_socket_num=0):
    """Links from_node to to_node"""
    node_tree.links.new(from_node.outputs[from_socket_num], to_node.inputs[to_socket_num])

    return from_node, to_node

def create_node(node_tree, type_name, node_x_location, node_location_step_x=0):
    """Creates a node of type_name and returns the node object and the updated node_x_location"""
    node_obj = node_tree.nodes.new(type=type_name)
    node_obj.location.x = node_x_location
    node_x_location += node_location_step_x
    return node_obj, node_x_location

def update_geo_node_tree(node_tree):
    """Updates the geo node tree"""

    """--- Set Node Locations ---"""
    node_x_location = 0
    node_location_step_x = 300

    """--- Create Nodes ---"""

    #Set Input and Output Node 
    in_node = node_tree.nodes["Group Input"]
    out_node = node_tree.nodes["Group Output"]

    #Create Combine XYZ Node
    combine_xyz_node, node_x_location = create_node(node_tree, "ShaderNodeCombineXYZ", node_x_location, node_location_step_x)

    #Create Mesh Cube
    mesh_cube_node, node_x_location = create_node(node_tree, "GeometryNodeMeshCube", node_x_location, node_location_step_x)

    """--- Create Sockets ---"""
    node_tree.interface.new_socket('Width', socket_type='NodeSocketFloat', in_out='INPUT', description='Width of the object')
    node_tree.interface.new_socket('Length', socket_type='NodeSocketFloat', in_out='INPUT', description='Length of the object')
    node_tree.interface.new_socket('Height', socket_type='NodeSocketFloat', in_out='INPUT', description='Height of the object')
    
    """--- Assign Sockets ---"""
    for socket in bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"].interface.items_tree:
        if socket.name == "Width":
            input_width = socket
        elif socket.name == "Height":
            input_height = socket
        elif socket.name == "Length":
            input_length = socket
        else:
            pass


    out_node.location.x = node_x_location

    """--- Set Node Links ---"""
    # link_nodes(node_tree,in_node,mesh_cube_node)
    link_nodes(node_tree,in_node,combine_xyz_node,1,0)
    link_nodes(node_tree,in_node,combine_xyz_node,2,1)
    link_nodes(node_tree,in_node,combine_xyz_node,3,2)
    link_nodes(node_tree,combine_xyz_node,mesh_cube_node)
    link_nodes(node_tree,mesh_cube_node,out_node)

    """--- Set Initial Node Values ---"""
    input_width.default_value = 4.0
    input_height.default_value = 6.0
    input_length.default_value = 8.0
    input_height.subtype = 'DISTANCE'
    input_width.subtype = 'DISTANCE'
    input_length.subtype = 'DISTANCE'



def generate_object():
    #Create Default Mesh
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=1)

    #Create Geometry Nodes Modifier
    bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_nodes_modifier()


    node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"]

    update_geo_node_tree(node_tree)

    """ Set Modifier Values Manually """
    bpy.data.objects["Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 8.0
    bpy.data.objects["Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_3"] = 10.0
    bpy.data.objects["Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_4"] = 12.0


################################################################
    # UI BEGIN
################################################################

class VIEW3D_PT_Object_Generator(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Object Generator"
    bl_label = "Object Generator"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Object Generator")

        """Generate the properties for the node group inputs"""
        for socket in bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"].node_group.interface.items_tree:
            if not socket.name == "Geometry":
                layout.prop(bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"].node_group.interface.items_tree[socket.name], "default_value" , text=socket.name)

def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_Object_Generator)
    
def unregister():
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_Object_Generator)

################################################################

def main():
    """Main Function"""
    clean_scene()
    generate_object()
    register()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, you can set the values through `bpy.data.objects["Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 8.0`

however when inside `draw()` there's no way to allow use of a slider to reflect real-time changes.

Comment: Blender has its own stack site